# Sharing contacts in android

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts

Im trying to share a contact using my android app, and Im stocked. Is there any way to share a contact directly using intents? Or do I have to send the contact information and re-build it in the other device? Also, is there any other way to do that without using intents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContactsContract` APIs to share a contact as a vcard file (e.g. to send via Whatsapp).

(I'm assuming you already have the contact's lookupKey, if you don't have it, let me know, and i'll add the code for getting it from contactId)

**UPDATE** added method to get LookupKey from ContactId

(make sure you import `Contacts` from `ContactsContract.Contacts`)

```
private String getLookupKey(long contactId) {
    String lookupKey = null;
    String[] projection = new String[]{Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY};
    String selection = Contacts._ID + "=" + contactId;
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            lookupKey = c.getString(0);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return lookupKey;
}

String lookupKey = getLookupKey(long contactId);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lookupKey)) {
    Log.e(TAG, "couldn't get lookupKey");
    return;
}
Uri shareUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, shareUri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share a contact");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks you for answer, Im sorry but I dont even know what a contact's lookupKey is, would you mind to explain me that and drop the code?

Comment: do you have a contact-id?

Comment: getLookupKey(long contactId); - how do we get contactId.. Sir

Answer (score 0):

The strategy I would use would be to fetch the desired contacts locally.  Then, parse these into JSON objects with the desired fields.  Either send the JSON to a server that the other user downloads from or send the JSON over bluetooth to other device.

Comment: I understand, but for example, if I want to send it via whatsapp, how can I do to make the json a contact object in whatsapp?